# Bœuf is the same as boeuf?

Tags: orthographe, typographie, alphabet, ligatures

My keyboard hasn't the word(s) *œ*, and that's why I want to know: is it correct to use *boeuf* instead? I mean, is *œ* the same as *oe*?